# Need clarification on how load balancers work please

Tags: load-balancing, system-design

I'm learning system design at the moment and have really hard time getting something: say I have to design a micro-service system and have very high load/bandwidth/whatever, so I will need something like this(multiple load balancers/servers/etc):
[check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoB2N.png)

But how should *exactly* load balancers structure look like? My thoughts are like this: One primary(like API gateway?) -> (n) secondaries -> servers/databases

But **the part** that **I** really **don't get** in the whole story is... how on earth does this **one**(it can't grow infinitely big after all) **server**(the API gateway/Primary load balancer) will be able to handle the whole load? Because after all, all the traffic will come through it, in and out... What am I missing here, please?